# How can i solve this vue related issue

Tags: vuejs2

Am trying to create a vue project using command line but it is showing this error message:

Error unexpected end ofJSON input while parsing near '....67e12ef","tarball":"h'

Using command line, I created a new project in C directory after which, I installed vue using NPM. After that I try installing @vue/CLI globally using NPM but while installing it the above error sprout out.

Have done npm cache clean  --force but still the same error..

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to suggest anything because your question lacks details.

However this error often appears as a problem with npm itself.

Consider cleaning npm's cache with following commands:

```
   npm cache clean --force
   npm cache verify
```

If the problem will still occur, please provide more details.